# print both image and string at the same time

Tags: php, image

This is maybe looks stupid question. But I'm having trouble to print both image and string(s) in web page.

My codes:

```
<?php
    $file = 'uploadedimages/' . end(end($collectedResult));
    // $file='demo.gif';
    if(file_exists($file)){
        header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64');
        //  $data=base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
        //  echo $data;
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        imagejpeg($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
    else
        echo 'No such file';

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    echo '<br><p>' . json_encode($collectedResult, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) . '</p>';
?>
```

With these codes image's showing in browser. It's OK. But some `json strings` aren't showing.

*I don't know where I should put the `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and/or `header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');` line(s).*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use header('content type') more than one time  . if your objetive is download a image with text on it search for PHP image framework  , if you just want to print a image and a text  renderit using `<img src='<?PHP echo $imageurlordata?>'>` and then the text you can also do someting like this

```
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
//  echo '<img src="image/base64:'.$data.'">';  // incorrect syntax
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$data.'">'; // you can change jpeg as png, gif or smth else...
```

or just use image url.
 I'm on phone sorry if there's any typo, hope its help you.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally what you want to do here is create a seperate php file with the image code and then include that within a standard image tag in the html. For example, something like this...(untested)

```
image.php
---------
<?php
    $file = 'uploadedimages/' . end(end($collectedResult));
    if( !file_exists( $file ) ) $file='/path/to/demo.gif';

    if(file_exists($file)){
        header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64');
        //  $data=base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
        //  echo $data;
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
        imagejpeg($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
?>

then in your html page
----------------------
<img src='image.php' alt='php generated image' />
<?php
    echo '<br><p>' . json_encode($collectedResult, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) . '</p>';
?>
```

Comment: thanks @RamRaider! But no result. I'm trying to improve these codes.

Answer (score 0):

**Content-Type** only one

You can do this:

```
<?php
echo '<img src="generated-image.php" />';
echo $jsongStr;
```